# QML temporary point object in JS context?

Tags: qt, qml

I'd like to make a "dummy" point object so I can call [`ChartView::mapToPosition`](http://doc.qt.io/QtCharts/qml-qtcharts-chartview.html#mapToPosition-method) from inside a function in a QML file.

However, this doesn't work:

```
function myFunction() {
    var temp_point = new Point(3, 5);
}
```

Nor does `new QPoint` or `new point` or simply `point`; all give a "not defined" error.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually reasonably clear from [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-point.html); I just didn't see the relevant sentence before posting my question.

Either of the following will work:

```
var temp_point = Qt.point(3, 5);
```

...or:

```
var temp_point = "3, 5";
```

Comment: @GrecKo There's a waiting period during which you can't accept your own answer, so I was going to wait until Monday. It appears to be over now, though.

Comment: oh okay, I wasn't aware of that period :)